# Two dimensional unordered_map

Tags: c++, 2d, unordered-map

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<int, void*> OneDimentionalNodes;
typedef boost::unordered_map<int, OneDimentionalNodes> TwoDimentionalNodes;

TwoDimentionalNodes nodes;
```

is this valid?

i don't use any hash functions since keys of the unordered_maps' are single integers.
it compiles, but when i iterate it like this, it crashes while trying to access this->hash_function()(k);

```
for (TwoDimentionalNodes::iterator it= nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end() ; ++it)
{
   for(OneDimentionalNodes::iterator it2 = nodes[it->first].begin(); it2 != nodes[it->first].end() ; ++it2)
    {
   // do stuff
    }
}
```

i'm also open to other containers with

- O(1) access
- O(n) iteration
- Sparse

Comment: Dimen*s*ion. Also, why not just go `it2->second.begin()`?

Comment: i tried it2->second.begin() too. it was the same result.

Comment: You can use std::unordered_map by including <unordered_map>, it comes with C++11, but is same as boost::unordered_map. Show us your `this->hash_function()(k);` code

Comment: @k06a it is where boost crashes, i dont think i need a hash function for this. do i?

Comment: Do you need to iterate over one specific dimension? (e.g. to get all [1][*] values).  If not, why not use a pair as the key for the unordered map (pair::first = first dimension, pair::second = second dimension).

Comment: @Mikbal, using it->second.begin() should be much faster than nodes[it->first].begin().  In your previous comment you said you used it2->second.begin().  Was this a typing error or not?  It should be it->second.begin().

Comment: Hi, just in case have a look also to Boost.MultiArray http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to iterator over all elements, and it is not required to loop over a specific dimension, then you could use a simple pair as key for your unordered_map, like this:

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> Coordinates;
typedef std::unordered_map<Coordinates,void *> TwoDimensionalNodes;
```

(notice I used STL instead of Boost, unordered_map is now also part of the standard STL).

Getting a specific value is simply writing:

```
twoDimensionalNodes[std::make_pair(x,y)]
```

(or use find if you're not sure if that value is in your map).

To iterate, just iterate over the unordered map:

```
for (auto it=twoDimensionalNodes.begin();it!=twoDimensionalNodes.end();++it)
   {
   std::cout << "x=" << it->first.first;
   std::cout << "y=" << it->first.second;
   std::cout << "value=" << it->second;
   }
```

To make it a bit more readable, I prefer getting the coordinates first from the iterator, like this:

```
for (auto it=twoDimensionalNodes.begin();it!=twoDimensionalNodes.end();++it)
   {
   Coordinates &coordinates = it->first;
   std::cout << "x=" << coordinates.first;
   std::cout << "y=" << coordinates.second;
   std::cout << "value=" << it->second;
   }
```

If you have more than 2 dimensions, use std::tuple, or simply write your own Coordinates class to be used as key for the map.

Comment: By the way, you need to specialize `std::hash` for your pair, as this was unfortunately ommited from the standard. Boost on the other hand has it.

Comment: pair works better. i dont have std::unordered_map, nonetheless it works perfect with boost::unordered_map, thank you

Comment: @Christian: I didn't know that you had to specialize std::hash if you used a pair as key.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::unordered_map` from `<unordered_map>`.
Try to specialize std hash class this way:

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T> 
    struct hash<void*>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(void * ptr) const
        {
            return (std::size_t)ptr;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Huh? He's using `int`s as keys, for which there should already be a `hash` specialization (there should also be one for pointers, too, anyway). And what about the multiple nested `stl` namespaces? Should that be a single `std` namespace (he's using boost, anyway, Ok should work the same there)?