# What does it mean to have void* as the second template parameter of an std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, unordered-map

I was looking at [Two dimensional unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10245382/925913) and saw

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> Coordinates;
typedef std::unordered_map<Coordinates,void *> TwoDimensionalNodes;
```

What does it mean to have a `void*` as the second parameter of the template?

I looked at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) of course and found no mention of `void`.

Comment: Second parameter is `T` - item value type.

Comment: `void*` is just a generic pointer type, it has nothing to do with `unordered_map` in particular, it's just used as a value type here just like any other type can be

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void

Comment: It probably means it is going to hold pointers to instances of potentially different types.  Before the values are used, they must be casted back into their original types.

Comment: This probably means the author has failed to design it in a type safe manner.

Comment: Indeed not type safe. Type erasure (a la `boost::any`) would have been more robust

Comment: I don't think it is even possible to create `std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, void *>` as there is no `std::hash` provided for `std::pair`... One would need to provide custom hasher there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second template arugment is the mapped type. By specifying `void*` you create a map where you can store objects of type `void*`.